# TS2322 when render custom Table from Ant Design using TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I'm getting these errors when I'm trying to render an custom Ant Desing Table:

```
semantic error TS2322: Type '{ columns: never[]; }' is not assignable to type
'IntrinsicAttributes & TableProps<any>'.   Property 'columns' does not exist on
type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TableProps<any>'.

semantic error TS2322: Type '{ dataSource: never[]; columns: never[]; }' is not
assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TableProps<any>'.   Property 'dataSource'
does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TableProps<any>'.
```

**Component** (dataSource and clumns are empty arrays, but the same issue is when I add any object values):

```
const DsrTable: FC = (): JSX.Element => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Table</h1>
            <Table
                dataSource={[]}
                columns={[]}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Table:**

```
declare const UTable: (props: TableProps<any>) => JSX.Element;

TableProps:
export interface TableProps<T> extends AntdTableProps<T> {
    mediaQueryLimit?: number;
}
```

**and the AntdTableProps:**

```
export interface TableProps<RecordType> extends Omit<RcTableProps<RecordType>, 'transformColumns' | 'internalHooks' | 'internalRefs' | 'data' | 'columns' | 'scroll' | 'emptyText'> {
    dropdownPrefixCls?: string;
    dataSource?: RcTableProps<RecordType>['data'];
    columns?: ColumnsType<RecordType>;
    pagination?: false | TablePaginationConfig;
    loading?: boolean | SpinProps;
    size?: SizeType;
    bordered?: boolean;
    locale?: TableLocale;
    onChange?: (pagination: TablePaginationConfig, filters: Record<string, FilterValue | null>, sorter: SorterResult<RecordType> | SorterResult<RecordType>[], extra: TableCurrentDataSource<RecordType>) => void;
    rowSelection?: TableRowSelection<RecordType>;
    getPopupContainer?: GetPopupContainer;
    scroll?: RcTableProps<RecordType>['scroll'] & {
        scrollToFirstRowOnChange?: boolean;
    };
    sortDirections?: SortOrder[];
    showSorterTooltip?: boolean | TooltipProps;
}
```

Unfortunetly I cannot change any Table properties and code. I can only customize the DsrTable coponent.

Comment: maybe your `AntdTableProps` doesn't get imported correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem has been solved.
I was building the library using node v.14.
After the change to 16 all works like a charm.